# Losing information when converting from character to numerical

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert characters like "9.230" to a numeric type.
First I erased the dots, because it was returning me "NA", and then I converted to numerical.
The problem is that when I convert to numerical I lose the trailing zero:

Example:

> a<-9.230
>
> as.numeric(gsub(".","",a,fixed=TRUE))

Returns: 923

Does anyone know how avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Look for result of

```
a<-9.230
gsub(".","",a,fixed=TRUE)
#[1] "923"
```

Question will be why? Because `fixed=TRUE` have been used in argument of `gsub`. Hence `.` is replaced by the 2nd argument of `gsub` that is `""`.

Basically thats the reason why `as.numeric(gsub(".","",a,fixed=TRUE))` is resulting in `923`

There is another point. How `a <- 9.230` was changed to `character` in `gsub` function. This has been explained in `r` documentation for `gsub`:

> Arguments:  x, text
>   a character vector where matches are sought, or an object
>   which can be coerced by as.character to a character vector. Long
>   vectors are supported.

Final question: How to avoid such behavior?

Dont use `gsub`. Use `sprintf("%.3f",a)`

Comment: Actually I just find out that the root of the problem is that: I'm importing different csv files with data in the format below:
Eg1:"1.920", Eg2:"111.943", Eg:"234".

When Rstudio reads the files, the right 0 from "eg1(1.920)" is disappearing. Returning: 1.92

>read.csv(file, header=TRUE, sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,encoding = "UTF-8")

Is there any formula to avoid losing data?

Comment: @fprado perhaps no. The only way is to read the data in `character` format and keep it in `character` format.

Comment: @fprado - you're confusing what's printed to the screen and how the number is stored. 9.230 is identical to 9.23, but you can print out numbers with a consistent number of decimals as MKR has shown - `sprintf("%.3f", c(9.23,1,700.3456))`

Comment: It just occurs to me that this might be a locale related problem. The period is used as a decimal point in some locales and as a thousands separator in others. What is the exact format and intended meaning in your Excel files? I don't know r (so I'm not qualified to answer about the read.csv function) but this is a common source of confusion with number parsing especially in locales where period is used as thousands separator.

Comment: This is exactly the problem  Hans-Martin Mosner. This data is from Brazil where "." is used as thousands. The problem is that when Rstudio reads the csv.file the "." means decimals. So I lose data from the beginning turning Eg. 1.920 (one thousand nine hundred and twenty into a number of one unit

Answer (score 1):

You assign the number 9.230 which is the same as 9.23. How is the system supposed to know that there was a trailing zero? If you want to transform a string, work with the string "9.230".